libClang.dll DllNotFoundException on Visual Studio Extensibility (VSX) project
Hellow there !
I am trying to use "CppAst.Net" nugget in a visual studio extensibility project, So far, when doing it in a classic c# project everything work fine, but when trying in a VSX project I get a runtime error : "System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'libclang' or one of its dependencies: Module could not be found".
Here some repro steps :

Create a new project using VisualStudio.Extensibility Extension template
Instal "CppAst" nugget (here version 0.16.0)
In file "command1.cs" and method "ExecuteCommandAsync" paste this parsing example :

var compilation = CppParser.Parse(@"enum MyEnum { MyEnum_0, MyEnum_1 }; void function0(int a, int b); struct MyStruct { int field0; int field1;};typedef MyStruct* MyStructPtr;");

Run extension and click on the command (Command is located here : Extension -> Sample remote command)

Here some other infos :

After looking to both project settings they look the same and same target framework (.NET 8.0).
When checking the CallStack the start work well (CppAst.dll and ClangSharp.Interlop.dll) to the call to libClang.dll.
When checking the bin folder every dlls are present.

I'm starting to run out of ideas on how to make it work.

devenv.exe should based on .net framework. But the package only supports .net 8.0

As far as I know, devenv.exe is based on .net framework. If you create a vsx project, it should also be based on .net framework. The situation you encountered should be because the package and project are incompatible, which is why there is no problem with ordinary class library projects. The cppast package itself is a package for .net 8.0.

"the package and project are incompatible": How so?  The OP says they are targeting .net 8.0.

Sorry for very late response, devenv.exe is indeed based .net framework, but here I am using visual studio extensibility to run extension in another process and be able to not be fully dependent of devenv limitations (when creating a vsx project it is .net8.0 by default)

@Tamaho Hi, trying using this: Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies Method, since there is libclang.dll in the bin, I think the issue comes from the reference lacking. :)
